# How do I read an HDF5 object reference in C++

Tags: c++, hdf5

I would like to read an HDF5 file using C++ that has an array of object references. I can get the correct results in python, but I have had trouble in C++.

I tried a few C examples from the tutorial documents, but it looks like the C++ wrappers are missing, and it is difficult to fill in the gaps.

```
H5File file = H5File("example.h5", H5F_ACC_RDONLY);  
DataSet dataset = file.openDataSet("units/electrode_group");  
H5T_class_t type_class = dataset.getTypeClass();  
cout << type_class << endl; // correctly obtains H5T_REFERENCE.    
// Need to read and apply the references next.
```

The following python code does everything I want, but I need a c++ version.

```
import h5py               
FileName = 'example.h5'    
myHDF5file = h5py.File(FileName)  
ElectrodeGroup = myHDF5file['units/electrode_group']  
for electrodeRef in ElectrodeGroup:  
    print(myHDF5file[electrodeRef].name)
```

The python code correctly prints:

```
/general/extracellular_ephys/shank1  
/general/extracellular_ephys/shank1  
/general/extracellular_ephys/shank2   
/general/extracellular_ephys/shank3
```

Comment: I haven't used references in awhile, so I can't help, sorry. Have you tried `H5Rget_name` and other [reference API](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5R.html#Reference-GetName)?

Comment: Unrelated, but I started using the wrapper [HighFive](https://github.com/BlueBrain/HighFive) to simplify things.

Comment: Thank you Timothy Brown. The H5Rget_name function worked for a test. I have to clean up the code and test some more, but I think I am set now.

Answer (score 0):

Though the OP got this to work using the C API, in case you (like I) came here through Google and want a C++ API answer:

The HDF5 C++ API documentation just sucks.  I painstakingly cross-correlated the C API documentation with what I found by searching around in the C++ API headers and comparing with what `h5dump` told me about an `.h5` I had that had region references in it.  Eventually I discovered that there are two important methods:

- [H5::H5Location::dereference()](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/class_h5_1_1_h5_location.html#a43fe9cb23e4ab9dd1004308661be59c3)
- [H5::H5Location::getRegion()](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/class_h5_1_1_h5_location.html#a5d0a971d157cffc3591f6d2d8b43dcca)

The trick is that because `H5Location` is an abstract class, you have to call them on instances of a concrete derived class.  In the case of this question one just wants the `dereference()` one, which fills a `H5Location` object with the thing that's pointed to by a reference (sort of unintuitive, IMHO, but that's what it does).  In this case we know that the thing the ref points to is a `DataSet`, so we just make a `DataSet` directly and call its `dereference()` argument.  (If your reference were a *subset* of the records in the pointed-to dataset, you can then use the `getRegion()` method to get a `DataSpace` pointing to the selected elements.)

Because the dataset contains *only* a set of refs, I think you do something like:

```cpp
// create holder for the references when they're read
// references are of type `hdset_reg_ref_t`
std::vector<hdset_reg_ref_t> refs(dataset.getSpace().getSimpleExtentNdims());

// read them out of the dataset.  
// `H5::PredType::STD_REF_DSETREG` is the H5 internal type for region references
dataset.read(refs.data(), H5::PredType::STD_REF_DSETREG);

for (const auto & ref : refs)
{
  // we know these are dataset region refs,
  // so we create DataSet objects directly
  H5::DataSet ds_ref;
  // make the dataset point to the right object using the reference
  ds_ref.dereference(file, ref, H5R_DATASET_REGION);  
  std::cout << ds_ref.getObjName() << "\n";

  // if you wanted to use the corresponding DataSpace
  // (say, your region ref was to a subset of records),
  // you'd grab it by doing:
  // H5::DataSpace dspc_ref = file.getRegion(ref);
}
```